# Define criteria on entity as criteria on entity attribute

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am using Hibernate Criteria Builder to query a table - let's call the table "Target". That entity has a child table called "Condition" (One to Many), and this is the relevant code in the target entity:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "target_id")
@NotNull
private List<Condition> expression;
```

I want to query "Target" by the "value" column in the "Condition" table - that is the only filter I want to allow on the child entity. How can I achieve this using Criteria Builder?

Comment: see this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56806095/spring-boot-jpa-criteria-api-select-single-column/56806344#56806344